# Как установить фокус внутри делегата ListView?

Tags: qt, qt5, qml

Есть ListView. Он содержит составной делегат, внутри которого есть TextField:

```
Window {
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: textModel
        ListElement {
            text: "Bill Smith"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "John Brown"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "Sam Wise"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        width: 180; height: 200
        focus: true

        model: textModel
        delegate: RowLayout{
            id: layout
            Label {
                text: model.text
            }
            TextField {
                text: model.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как установить фокус на первый TextField в списке? Если просто задать `focus: true` внутри ListView, то это не помогает.

Если сделать делегат ListView простым, а не составным, то фокус устанавливается:

```
    ListView {
        width: 180; height: 200
        focus: true

        model: textModel
        delegate: TextField {
            text: model.text
        }
    }
```

Но мне нужен составной делегат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: textModel
        ListElement {
            text: "Bill Smith"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "John Brown"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "Sam Wise"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        width: 180
        height: 200

        focus: true

        model: textModel

        delegate: RowLayout{
            onActiveFocusChanged: field.forceActiveFocus()

            Label {
                text: model.text
            }
            TextField {
                id: field

                text: model.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

одно из возможных решений добавить в делегате обработку сигнала

```
onActiveFocusChanged: field.forceActiveFocus()
```

в таком случае фокус будет попадать в TextField

Comment: Проверил - работает.